# What does "The type T must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter" mean?

Tags: c#, generics, controller

I'm trying to create a generic controller on my C#/MVC/Entity Framework application.

```
public class GenericRecordController<T> : Controller
{
    private DbSet<T> Table;
    // ... 

    public action()
    {
        // ... 
        db.Entry(T_Instance).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

However the `DbSet<T>` and **`T_Instance`** line has a compiler error.

> The type **`T`** must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter.

When I constrain it as a `class`, it was solved.

```
Controller where T : class
```

**What does the error mean?** I'm not asking for a solution, I would like to understand why this error occurs and why constraining it as a `class` solves it.

Comment: Incomplete and unclear. Also, a debatable design choice.

Comment: @HenkHolterman . Why a bad design choice?

Comment: It makes your controllers Model oriented, they should be View oriented. Unnecessary for CRUD, harmful for all other purposes.

Comment: Where does T_Instance come from? Why is it different from T ?

Comment: I understand. This class is a parent will have some generic methods (list, delete. etc ) only. My Other controller classes will inherit from this parent. "class CustomerController : GenericController ... " So, i don't think it is a bad design. just avoiding some repeated code. Thanks for your advice @HenkHolterman

Answer (score 153, accepted):

If you look at the definition of `DbSet<TEntity>`:

```
public class DbSet<TEntity> : DbQuery<TEntity>, IDbSet<TEntity>, IQueryable<TEntity>, IEnumerable<TEntity>, IQueryable, IEnumerable, IInternalSetAdapter 
where TEntity : class
```

Because it has a [`type constraint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) that the generic type must be a `class` then you must initialize it with a type that also matches this condition:

```
public class GenericRecordController<T> : Controller where T : class
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 49):

They apparently have a constraint on the generic type.

All you need to change is:

```
public class GenericRecordController<T> : Controller where T : class
```

This tells the compiler that only reference types may be supplied as a type for T.

Answer (score 36):

You can do it on just a method as well:

```
public bool HasKey<T>(T obj) where T : class
{
    return _db.Entry<T>(obj).IsKeySet;
}
```