# How to pass C# generic type to another class

Tags: c#, generics

Is there any way to write the following code in C#?

```
public T GetRandomRecord<T>(DbSet<T> set)
{
    return set.OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

It gives me the following error:

> Error CS0452  The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it
>   as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'DbSet'

`DbSet` is the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet`.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try a [generic type constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx). `class` in this context will constrain `T` to be a reference type. Callers won't be able to call `GetRandomRecord<DateTime>(dbSet)`, because `DateTime` is a struct. This will be enforced by the compiler.

```
public T GetRandomRecord<T>(DbSet<T> set) where T : class
{
    // ... stuff
}
```

This is required because `DBSet<TEntity>` has the same constraint:

```
public class DbSet<TEntity> 
    : DbQuery<TEntity>, 
      IDbSet<TEntity>, 
      IQueryable<TEntity>, 
      IEnumerable<TEntity>, 
      IQueryable, 
      IEnumerable 
      where TEntity : class
    //  M... O... U... S... EEEEE....
{
```

So the compiler won't let you do what you're doing until you can guarantee that you will respect that constraint that `DbSet` has. You can provide that guarantee by applying the same constraint to your own method, which tells the compiler to leave you alone and go spout that cryptic error message at your callers instead.

Comment: And why it is required?

Comment: @FrozenHeart In this case, probably because `DbSet<T>` has a the same constraint on its own type parameter `T`.

Comment: @FrozenHeart Yep, I just checked, and it has the same constraint. `where TEntity : class`

Comment: @EdPlunkett No. Otherwise, compile-time error would occur. EF is doing some runtime checks.

Comment: @pwas A compile time error *is* occurring.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - good for adding the definition of the DbSet :)

Comment: Ah, right :-) anyway - IT is also required when using generics and LINQ :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add a constraint to your method

```
public T GetRandomRecord<T>(DbSet<T> set) where T : class
```

Comment: And why it is required?

Comment: Adding to Ed's comment above, restricting the constraint to a class means the method will only allow a reference type which is required in this case - See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38483145/2779990